# How to get tables registered as spark table into data frame

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

I have imported tables from PostgreSQL database into spark-sql using spark-thriftserver jdbc connection and now from beeline I can see these tables.

Is there any way I can convert these tables into spark data frame.

Answer (score 8):

This works with Spark > 2.0:

`df = spark.table('table')`

Answer (score 1):

**spark 2.0.0**
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html

The sql function on a SparkSession enables applications to run SQL queries programmatically and returns the result as a DataFrame.

```
# spark is an existing SparkSession
df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM table")
```

**spark 1.6.2**
http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/sql-programming-guide.html

Running SQL Queries Programmatically

The sql function on a SQLContext enables applications to run SQL queries programmatically and returns the result as a DataFrame.

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
df = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM table")
```

Answer (score 1):

This is more straightforward (**spark2.4**):

```
df = spark.table('your_table')
display(df)
```